# Shooting to the center of the screen

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This code is used to fire laser straight forward.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class LeftGun : MonoBehaviour {

public Rigidbody laser;
public AudioClip LaserShot;

float shotSpeed = 0.1f;
bool canShoot = true;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    if(!Engine.escape)
    {
        shotSpeed -= Time.deltaTime;

        if(shotSpeed <= 0f)
            canShoot = true;

        if(Input.GetButton("Fire1") && canShoot)
        {
            shotSpeed = 0.1f;
            canShoot = false;
            PlayerGUI.ammunition--;
            audio.PlayOneShot(LaserShot);
            Rigidbody clone = Instantiate(laser,transform.position, transform.rotation) as Rigidbody;
            clone.velocity = transform.TransformDirection(-80, 0, 0);
            Destroy(clone.gameObject, 3);
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to fire to the center of the screen (where crosshair is). How can I achive that?
Example image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHLZI.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Camera.ScreenPointToRay](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenPointToRay.html). To get the ray from center of the main camera, use:

```
float x = Screen.width / 2f;
float y = Screen.height / 2f;

var ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(new Vector3(x, y, 0));
clone.velocity = ray.direction * laserSpeed;
```

laserSpeed is a public float which is the speed with which you want the laser to travel at. You can change it according to your needs (for the code you provided, laserSpeed would be 80).

Comment: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object  
LeftGun.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/LeftGun.cs:33) @Edit Solved. Used public Camera myCamera; and var ray = myCamera.ScreenPointToRay(new Vector3(x, y, 0)); Now it works. Thank you.

Comment: @Oen44 you must not have the MainCamera tag on your main camera that's why... But good to know that it worked.