# Get touch location on screen for perspective Camera

Tags: unity-game-engine

As the title of the question goes, I am trying to get the touch location on screen for perspective Camera.

Pretty much when I click a button my character has the ability to "teleport" or change it's location/transform to the same area of my finger with the Z axis hard coded.

Now I stress "Perspective Camera" because when the camera is Orthographic the following works fine.

```
    if (canTeleport == true) {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {


            //fingerPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(0).position); 
            //  fingerPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition); //Desktop
            //  transform.position = fingerPos;
            //  Debug.Log (transform.position);


            //Needed for Mouse
            //fingerPos = Input.mousePosition;
            //Needed for Finger                
            fingerPos = Input.GetTouch(0).position;


            //Oth Camera
            fingerPos.z = -36.1f;
            fingerPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (fingerPos); 

            //Pers Camera
           // Vector3 screenPosition= new Vector3(0,0,0);
             //fingerPos = GetWorldPositionOnPlane(screenPosition, -36.1f);

            fingerPos.z = -36.1f;
            transform.position = fingerPos;
            Debug.Log (transform.position);

            canTeleport = false;
        }
    }
```

But when in perspective it does not, I understand 2D and 3D space is different but only thing that should matter is the Z axis and i'm hard codding the Z axis so im not sure why it does not work.

any help offered will be appreciated.

thank you.

Update
[image]

The circle area is where I touched and as you can see my sprite went to the location on the canvas not in the game world.

Comment: You probably want [Camera#ScreenPointToRay()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenPointToRay.html) and then perform a physics raycast.

Comment: Possible duplicate. Here is a solution though https://stackoverflow.com/a/29863218/8126132 key part is Camera.ScreenPointToRay and of course combined with a Physics.Raycast

Comment: @MrDos I havent been able to solve despite using the link provided. 
                `float x = Screen.width;
                float y = Screen.height;var ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(new Vector3(x, y, -36.1f));`
if Ray has the position that I touched, I cannot set it to a vector which is my position.

Comment: @Draco18s I did that with the X and Y of the vector3 being X and Y of the touch but I think i might need help with the ray cast.

Comment: Once you have  ray you need to pass that ray to [`Physics.Raycast()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html) or [`Physics2D.Raycast()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Raycast.html) depending on your setup.

Comment: @Draco18s did you notice the image i uploaded? I am looking at the raycast method and i don't see where the transform of the objected is updated or can be

Comment: In the image you added, what sprite were you trying to move? `Camera.ScreenPointToRay` uses the projection of the camera so I don't know why you're showing us UI elements... Could you clarify a bit what you're trying to achieve? Move what?

Comment: @MrDos Ok, I am trying to move my player. In the Game view my player was standing in the air. My goal was when I touch the teleport button my character will be moved to the location of my touch. So I circled the area I touched with is the top right corner, I showed the scene view to show that my character was indeed moved. but it seems to use the ui canvas to calculate where it should go. As you can see from the scene view it goes to the location just above button and not stick the little blue box in the bottom left which is my game area

Comment: Got it. I'm pretty sure it's due to your raycasting. What layer(s) are you casting on? You might want to exclude UI from your layer mask to see if it works.
If your character doesn't have to be on a special object to teleport, I would say that raycast isn't the best approach (it requires a collider to register). There might be a better way of doing it but this should do the trick: `var ray = Camera.ScreenPointToRay` to get a forward vector from the camera with perspective. Then `transform.position = Camera.main.position + ray.direction * distance` to offset the object `distance` units away

Comment: @MrDos                `var ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(new Vector3(x, y, -36.1f));
                transform.position = Camera.main.transform.position + ray.direction * -36.1f;`
Moves the sprite to only 1 area no matter where I touch, There is no where I can specify X and Y of a touch? Correct me if im wrong but in 3D X and Y is "constant" and the only difference is the Z axis

Comment: @MrDos I also tried `  var ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.touches[0].position);` , sprite moves but still not to my touch location. I think the mistake is in my transform.postion code